# Result of mongoose.save is incorrect when adding item to mixed schema array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Following is a function that shows the issue:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017');

connection.once('open', function () {
  var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    obj: [{}] //mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  });

  var Model = connection.model('mtest', schema);
  var model = new Model({
    obj: [{ name: 'Original' }]
  });

  model.save(function (err, res) {
    console.log('result 1', res);

    Model.findOne({_id: res._id}, function (err, res) {
      res.obj[0].name = 'Modified';
      res.obj.push({ name: 'other' });
      //res.markModified('obj'); // using markModified does not help

      res.save(function (err, res) {
        console.log('result 2', res);
        connection.close();
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  })
});
```

The output of "result 2" shows "`Modified`" for the first item in "obj": `obj: [ { name: 'Modified' }, { name: 'other' } ]`.
However, in the database the value of the first item is still "`Original`".

This only happens when pushing a second item into the array (otherwise the first item is indeed modified).
Adding `markModified` does resolve the issue.

I'm using an array of empty objects types in the schema because in reality this use case deals with with schemas that inherit from each other, so no single schema can be used here.

Is it a bug? The only workaround I've found is to clear the array and add all the items again. I'd like to know if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either alter your `markModified` call to identify the index of the element you changed "outside" of the array access methods:

```javascript
res.obj[0].name = 'Modified';
res.obj.push({ name: 'other' });
res.markModified('obj.0');
```

Or switch to using the `set` array access method to alert `name` (which looks pretty goofy, but does work):

```javascript
res.obj[0].name = 'Modified';
res.obj.set(0, res.obj[0]);
res.obj.push({ name: 'other' });
```

Comment: Thanks. Got a similar answer on the mongoose github issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3658